# how to have this text row be above text instead of next to it

Tags: html

So im coding this price calculator and im  trying to have Rabatt be above Jährlich how would i do that while having it in the table class="hiddenMonthly".I had it above Jährlich but it wasnt in the table class="hiddenMonthly" so my hide function wouldnt work.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="./app.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container" >
      <div style="width: 270px"class="grid-item">
        <header>Preiskalkulator</header>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
          App-Benutzer: <br>
          <input id="Appuserrangecolor" value="0" type="range" rangecolorid="Appuserrangecolor" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateUser(this.value, 'Appuserrangecolor');" class='appuser updatecolor'></input>
          <input class='updatecolor' style="width: 30px;border-color: var(--form_border_color);" type="text" id="AppInput" value="0" placeholder="1-100" rangecolorid="Appuserrangecolor" min="0" max="100" oninput="this.value = this.value > 100 ? 100 : Math.abs(this.value); updateUser(this.value, 'AppInput');"><br>
          Bürosoftware-Benutzer: <br>
          <input id="Backendrangecolor" value="1" type="range" rangecolorid="Backendrangecolor" min="1" max="15" oninput="updateUser(this.value, 'Backendrangecolor'); " class='backenduser updatecolor'></input>
          <input class='updatecolor' style="width: 30px;border-color: var(--form_border_color);" type="text" id="BackendInput" rangecolorid="Backendrangecolor" value="1" min="1" max="15" placeholder="1-15" oninput="this.value = this.value > 15 ? 15 : Math.abs(this.value,); updateUser(this.value, 'BackendInput');"><br>
        </div>
        <b > Bürosoftware wählen </b>
        <select style="width: 150px;background-color:rgba(96,125,139,0.33)" id = "backendfunktion" onchange = "calcSum()" >
          <option value="Z">Zeiterfassung</option>
          <option value="ZR"> Zeiterfassung + Rechnungswesen</option>
        </select>
        <select style="width: 150px;background-color:rgba(96,125,139,0.33)" id = "zahlrythmus" onchange = "calcSum();checkHide(this)" >
          <option onclick="('hidden')" value="J">Jährlich</option>
          <option value="M">monatlich</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="width: 270px">
        <table style="width:100%;text-align: right;">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 138px" >App-Benutzer<br > <div class='text-grey'>pro <span class="proapp" >7.50</span>€</div></td>
            <td style="width: 62px; vertical-align: top;" class='appanzahl'>0.00€</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bürosoftware-Benutzer<br ><div class='text-grey'>pro <span class='probackend'>20.00</span>€</div></td>
            <td class='backendpreissum' style="vertical-align: top;">20.00€</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td >Gesamtpreis mtl.:<br><div class='text-grey'>(zzgl. MwSt)</div></td>
            <td class='summe' style="vertical-align: top;">20.00€</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="hiddenMonthly">
            <td >Rabatt<br></td>
            <td class='rabattsum'>0.00€</td>
            <td>Jährlich<br></td>
            <td class='jaehrlichsum'>240.00€</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: put them in different table rows?

Comment: i need it to be in id="hiddenmonthly"

Comment: OK, a a nested table within  `hiddenMonthly` with two rows